# Python Script: Runs in Shell but fails in real life because cant import module

Tags: python, import, shebang

I have a script that runs fine in the Python Shell, but when double clicked it fails to import the PIL module(but it does import the PIL module in the Shell).

What is wrong? Do I need a different shebang? I am on Windows 7:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""

"""

try:
    from   PIL import Image
    import os
    import datetime
    import time

except Exception, e:
    raw_input(str(e))

# Running this script in the Shell, the code gets to here
# Running this script in real life (just double click it) it prints "no module PIL"
```

Comment: I dont have experience with running in the cmd, do I cd/navigate to the python.exe to open it or do I navaigate to the script directory & say "python myscript.py"?

Comment: @Mack: Sorry, I interpreted "shell" above as `cmd`, and asked for the command line you used.  Now I saw you said "Python shell".

Comment: @Sven Marnach: After running command line, its the smae output "No module named PIL"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the difference between Shell, and "real life". It's all real. But when you double click on it it may be running a different version of Python. Do you have multiple versions installed?

Comment: @Keith: I do have 2 versions of python 2.5 & 2.7. The PYTHONPATH environment variable is this "C:/Python27/python.exe" is that correct?

Comment: @Mack `PYTHONPATH` should be set to the folder with your python modules, not the executable. It's probably unnecessary to muck with, if you are using 2.7 make sure you have PIL installed for in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL`, and if not download the installer for 2.7 from their website. Then make sure that `c:\Python27\python.exe` is used to open the .py files by Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Add the lines

```
import sys
print sys.executable
```

to your code.  You'll see that it's a different python executable when you run it in the shell, vs. double clicking the .py file.

If you want to control which installed version of python is used to run your script, rather than simply running the script, type something like the following in a windows command window.

```
c:\python27\python.exe scriptname.py
```

replacing the python directory and script name as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Windows ignores the shebang line (even if it would respect it, it wouldn't be able to execute `/usr/bin/env` -- it doesn't exist on Windows).  Double-clicking in the explorer starts the script with the program associated with the `.py` extension.  Check that you have set this to the right version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have PIL installed for a different version of Python than is set to open .py files in Windows. PIL installs itself into `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL` if you are using Python 2.7, in which case you'd want to make sure Windows opens .py files with `C:\Python27\python.exe`. You can right click on the .py file, click Open With -> Choose default program... to set it to the version of Python you've installed PIL for.

Comment: Munging with PYTHONPATH is usually a mistake, and it doesn't explain why it does work "in the Shell".

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too but realized I needed to update the `app.yaml` file. Paste this under `libraries`:

```
- name: PIL
  version: "1.1.7"
```