# Import quandl works in python3 shell but not in script

Tags: python-3.x, shell, import

I am trying to do a machine learning tutorial, but for some reason, I get an error when importing quandl from the script, yet I can import it fine from the shell?

file is called regression1.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
import quandl

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
df = df[['Adj. Open', 'Adj. High', 'Adj. Low', 'Adj. Close', 'Adj. Volume',]]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] * 100.0

df = df[['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj. Volume']]   
print(df.head)
```

and here is the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./regression1.py", line 4, in <module>
    import quandl
ImportError: No module named 'quandl'
```

What's up here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to this issue, and I refer to this question:
[Python Script: Runs in Shell but fails in real life because cant import module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366282/python-script-runs-in-shell-but-fails-in-real-life-because-cant-import-module)

I am running virtualenv, but in my script I used the shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

If I change this to:

```
#/home/me/Programming/virtual_environments/mlearn_env/python
```

i.e. my virtual environment for this particular exercise, it works fine. So be aware of what you are running and from where. I have to admit, it has not happened before, I have been able to use virtualenv with the initial shebang for all other programs run, but it seems some particular modules are a little stubborn and are not written with a different path in mind.

Please correct me if I am incorrect in my thinking.